# Get Speech To Text from "ok Google"

Tags: android, service, keyword, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I want a background service to listen to the keyword or hot word , the API is 17 minutes and the minimum API to integrate hot Word is 21. But integrating " Ok Google " in my application i can get the voice-text. The problem is that I can't get the text..

In the manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can i get the speech text in my app?